# Config attributes in <html> with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view, tags

Generally Rails main application views/layout omits the `<html>` tag, focusing on defining what should be inside of it, like the `<head>` and `<body>` tags.

What I'm actually trying to do is to define a simple attribute inside of the `<html>` top level tag, but I don't know where to write it.

*Any tips?*

Answer (score 1):

It's available in `application.html.erb` in the `views/layout` folder

This file in included by default in all your views.

Comment: The application layout in my rails app was only defining `<head>` and `<body>` tags. The `<html>` was not defined in there.

Added and it's now working. Thank you.